# What is the size (in memory) of a number?

Tags: javascript

What is the size of a number in JavaScript?

For example, I know a single char in C is 1 byte. The size of an int is `sizeof(int)`. The size on an int64_t is 64 bits, and so on.

What (and how to find it) is the size of a number (decimal, float) in JavaScript?

Comment: javascript has only `Number` - and it is a 64bit "double" [IEEE Standard 754](http://steve.hollasch.net/cgindex/coding/ieeefloat.html)

Comment: You are explicitly isolated from low-level details like this in Javascript (and most high level languages for that matter).

Comment: `int64_t` is 64 **bits**. Just saying

Comment: @Amit Yes, sorry, that was a typo.

Comment: I have no right to ask this question but why would you want to do this? If it's for any purpose that includes the substring *"perf"* e.g. like *perf*ormance it's not worth thinking about, you're likely to make your code **much more unreadable** by applying useless micro-optimisations which is a bad thing for the future you and other future maintainers of your project ;)

Comment: Thanks to optimizations in implementations it is not always 64bit, rather you guaranteed that you will get fully compatible behavior. Engines may use shorter/faster/whatever else values under the hood as long as their optimization engine decided they can get away with it.

Comment: @SidneyLiebrand I'm trying to find out the size of a memoized function that will have to deal with a big number of data.

Comment: @alexandernst Ultimately you're only going to know this for sure by running it.

Comment: @alexandernst Are you talk about number value of number object?

Comment: @deceze Yes, but I want to know if it's actually reasonable to even implement it. I mean, there are going to be `a lot of` different values.

Comment: Presumably the *worst case* would be 64bits, so use that as a basis for roughly ball parking your algorithm. But again, depending on the concrete implementation and engine, you won't know for sure until you actually run it. I'd build a small test case to get a rough idea instead of trying to find theoretical information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't determine memory size of number value size in JS. It is engine-specific and can be different between different values in same engine. ECMAScript standard (e.g. [ECMA-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.19)) only defines *observable behavior* of numbers, but as long as behavior matches specification in the end, different JS VMs use all kinds of different number types under the hood for optimization purposes.

Standard sets no limits on what engines can use and defines no method to retrieve those implementation details. Nor any other part of spec relies on anything except *observable behavior* again. You can check out engine-specific details in its documentation or try engine-specific internals debugging tools, but you can't get this size data from JS code itself.

Comment: Can you give me a link to the relevant part of the docs of the engines of Chrome/FF?

Comment: `It is engine-specific` - yet your link suggests that ECMA-262 mandates the format to be `IEEE Standard 754`

Comment: @JaromandaX The format/behaviour has to match, how the engine goes about storing it is it's own business.

Comment: @JaromandaX, its logic must correspond to IEEE standard. But interanlly engine may use anything else for optimization purposes, thus you cannot determine it's size as OP asked.

Comment: @JamesThorpe - yes, my bad, I didn't think "deep" enough

Answer (score 3):

Aside from what's mentioned in other answers, the reality is that modern engines use various optimizations, including storing numbers in various different methods (types...) depending on usage. This is one of the main ideas behind things like [asm.js](http://asmjs.org), and just to provide a simple example:

```
var i = 0;
while(i < 5) {
  console.log('hello');
  i++;
}
```

The engine can infer that `i` is an integer and optimize it's usage.