# How much space does Infinity take in memory?

Tags: javascript

How much space does `Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY` (aka `Infinity`) or `Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY` take in memory for Javascript?

Comment: The same as all values of type `number` (that aren’t optimized to integers): 8 bytes.

Comment: See [Memory Usage Of Different Data Types in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4905861/4642212) and [What is the size (in memory) of a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35652587/4642212).

Comment: infinity fits into finite space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Infinity is a number, and all numbers are 64 bit [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) floating point values, so therefore Infinity is a 64 bit (8 byte) floating point. Realistically this is such a tiny amount that you shouldn't worry about it. Chances are if you're using it a lot, it's only getting assigned to one instance in memory anyway.